# How to create Stored Proc in H2

Tags: stored-procedures, h2

I am pretty new to Hibernate. Could you please help me on below. I am trying to Create Stored Proc using ALIAS in h2 (in memory database). I have looked h2 database manual on that basis I have implemented below.

Java class:

```
    public class H2StoredProcedures {

          public static void load(Connection conn,String sql) {
               System.out.print("");
            //  File file = new File("src/test/resources/data/proc.sql");
              try {
                  conn.createStatement().execute(sql);
              } catch (SQLException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
```

Currently I am using hibernate version:1.4.197.below is the h2 engine code which is calling java method.

H2 Engine(sql file where I have schema and tables scripts):

```
DROP ALIAS IF EXISTS PROC;
CREATE ALIAS PROC FOR "com.util.h2.H2StoredProcedures.load";
CALL PROC('CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procPrintHelloWorld
IS
BEGIN

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(''Hello World!'');

END');
```

Error:

> Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE[*]

Full Error Msg:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE[*] LOADTEST (P_NAME IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Welcome '|| P_NAME);
END; "; expected "FORCE, VIEW, ALIAS, SEQUENCE, USER, TRIGGER, ROLE, SCHEMA, CONSTANT, DOMAIN, TYPE, DATATYPE, AGGREGATE, LINKED, MEMORY, CACHED, LOCAL, GLOBAL, TEMP, TEMPORARY, TABLE, SYNONYM, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, HASH, SPATIAL, INDEX"; SQL statement:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOADTEST (p_name IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line ('Welcome '|| p_name);
END; [42001-197]
```

Comment: H2 only supports stored procedures or functions written in Java

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. thanks for you comment.  I am passing stored proc script in java only. could you pls post some sample code for creating procedure in java?

Comment: The body of the functions needs to be written in Java. H2 has no PL/SQL or something similar. Plus: there is no `create procedure` statement in H2, you can only create an alias to a Java function (that needs to be in the classpath): http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_alias

Comment: Got it Thanks for help @a_horse_with_no_name